# What will happen if new data is added when snapshot is running in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, snapshot

I have scheduled snapshot of disk in GCP. What will happen if data is changed (insertion or deletion of new data) when snapshot is running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any data that is changed after a snapshot is started will persist on the disk but will not be part of the snapshot.

When a snapshot is started, the disk I/O is frozen. The system is notified before freezing the disk I/O so that buffers can be flushed, applications can flush data, etc. The state of the disk is determined and the snapshot begins. Any block changes during the snapshot result in Copy on Write (CoW), which duplicates the block in the backend storage system. The snapshot will store the block before CoW. This is to maintain disk image / file system consistency.